# Recurring 502 Bad Gateway issue

Tags: database

Hoping one of you out there can offer suggestions or at least tell me I'm not alone. Our WP site has had a random 502 Bad Gateway problem for few days now - happens once every few page loads. I've been down the server-side troubleshooting list (with help of Bluehost) and the my-side list (disabling all plugins, updating theme, latest PHP..) - everything on the site is up to date, and 2 bad plug-ins were removed.

Some online articles tell me if this happens once every few loads it's a server-side problem. The hosting company assures me it is a problem with the 'optimization of website or database' - whatever that great expanse of possibilities entails.

I'm running out of questions to ask - I just want my site to load each time somebody visits. Can anybody help?

Comment: Sounds like a memory issue. Check your phpinfo. Or ask Bluehost what it is set to and if it can be increased.

Comment: In your position after you've tried most reasonable things I'd be tempted to switch host. Shared hosting can affeced by so many other factors, for the sake of $5 or $10/month and a few hours to move your site you may be saving countless more hours, frustration or lost business/users.

Comment: Also you may want to install Query Monitor which will show you (for pages that do load successfully) high level info on memory usage, settings and query time.